# Can't Ask object property twice in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Forgive me for what might be terrible javascript code. This is my first time trying something in javascript...

```
function Tile (window_id, size)
{
  this.window_id = window_id;
  this.size = size;
};

function Desktop ()
{
  this.tiles = [];
  this.ntiles = function () {return this.tiles.length;};
  this.size = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.ntiles(); i++) {sum += this.tiles[i].size;};
    return sum;
  };

  this.addTile = function (tile)
  {
    if (this.size() === 1) {return -1;};
    this.tiles.push(tile);
    return 0;
  };
};

function Layer ()
{
  this.desktops = [];
  this.ndesktops =  function () {return this.desktops.length;};

  this.addDesktop = function (desktop)
  {
    this.desktops.push(desktop);
    return 0;
  };

  this.availableDesktopSize = function (size)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < this.ndesktops(); i++)
    {
      print(this.desktops[i].size());
      print('hi');
      print(this.desktops[i].size());
      print('hihi');
      var space = 1.0 - this.desktops[i].size();
      print('hihihi');
      print(space);
      print(size);
      if (space >= size) {return i;};
    };
    return -1;
  };
};

var layer = new Layer();

var desktop1 = new Desktop();
var desktop2 = new Desktop();

var tile = new Tile(100, 0.5);

desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop2.addTile(tile);

layer.addDesktop(desktop1);
layer.addDesktop(desktop2);

print(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.51));
print(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.49));
```

I'm trying to make a method for the Layer class that finds the first desktop that has enough space left. In trying to achieve this, while trying my code, I observed that for some reason when I call the desktop.size() property I get the right value back the first time but when I call it a second time my script dies. This is the output

```
1
hi
TypeError: Result of expression 'this.desktops[i]' [undefined] is not an object.
```

So it does the first print fine but why can't it do the exact same function another time?

(If you have any other advice to improve my code, that would be very helpfull)

Comment: `print` opens the print dialog, use `console.log` and then open the console usually by hitting `F12` on your keyboard.

Comment: @Mouser I'm not using javascript in a browser, but within the WM console of KDE Plasma and the tutorial suggested to use print() as it is provided through KWin. Hence the use of print(), but thank you very much for your suggestion nonetheless :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a global *i* variable in several loops.

You call a method from within such a loop, and that method has its own loop giving a different value to the same *i*  variable. So when you come back from that call *i* no longer is the same as before.

Solution: declare your variables as local variables.

```
for (let i = 0; // ...etc
//   ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` to declare your iterator variable `i` to bind it to the scope. Now you're using a global scoped `i` that is causing trouble.

However in modern browsers `let` would be better because that binds the variable to the block scope. The current `{}` preventing the value of that variable to be used outside of that block.

```js
function Tile (window_id, size)
{
  this.window_id = window_id;
  this.size = size;
};

function Desktop ()
{
  this.tiles = [];
  this.ntiles = function () {return this.tiles.length;};
  this.size = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.ntiles(); i++) {sum += this.tiles[i].size;}; //var i binds i to this function scope.
    return sum;
  };

  this.addTile = function (tile)
  {
    if (this.size() === 1) {return -1;};
    this.tiles.push(tile);
    return 0;
  };
};

function Layer ()
{
  this.desktops = [];
  this.ndesktops =  function () {return this.desktops.length;};

  this.addDesktop = function (desktop)
  {
    this.desktops.push(desktop);
    return 0;
  };

  this.availableDesktopSize = function (size)
  {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.ndesktops(); i++) //var i binds i to this function scope.
    {
      console.log(this.desktops[i].size());
      console.log('hi');
      console.log(this.desktops[i].size());
      console.log('hihi');
      var space = 1.0 - this.desktops[i].size();
      console.log('hihihi');
      console.log(space);
      console.log(size);
      if (space >= size) {return i;};
    };
    return -1;
  };
};

var layer = new Layer();

var desktop1 = new Desktop();
var desktop2 = new Desktop();

var tile = new Tile(100, 0.5);

desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop2.addTile(tile);

layer.addDesktop(desktop1);
layer.addDesktop(desktop2);

console.log(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.51));
console.log(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.49));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but it seems to be the way `i` is assigned in your for loops.
in this bit of code

```
  print(this.desktops[i].size());
  print('hi');
  print(this.desktops[i].size());
```

`i` is `0` but then is set to `2` in the line below

```
    for (i = 0; i < this.ntiles(); i++) {sum += this.tiles[i].size;};
```

```js
function Tile (window_id, size)
{
  this.window_id = window_id;
  this.size = size;
};

function Desktop ()
{
  this.tiles = [];
  this.ntiles = function () {return this.tiles.length;};
  this.size = function ()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.ntiles(); i++) {sum += this.tiles[i].size;};
    return sum;
  };

  this.addTile = function (tile)
  {
    if (this.size() === 1) {return -1;};
    this.tiles.push(tile);
    return 0;
  };
};

function Layer ()
{
  this.desktops = [];
  this.ndesktops =  function () {return this.desktops.length;};

  this.addDesktop = function (desktop)
  {
    this.desktops.push(desktop);
    return 0;
  };

  this.availableDesktopSize = function (size)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < this.ndesktops(); i++)
    {
      console.log(this.desktops[i].size());
      console.log(i)
      print('hi');
      print(this.desktops[i].size());
      print('hihi');
      var space = 1.0 - this.desktops[i].size();
      print('hihihi');
      print(space);
      print(size);
      if (space >= size) {return i;};
    };
    return -1;
  };
};

var layer = new Layer();

var desktop1 = new Desktop();
var desktop2 = new Desktop();

var tile = new Tile(100, 0.5);

desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop1.addTile(tile);
desktop2.addTile(tile);

layer.addDesktop(desktop1);
layer.addDesktop(desktop2);

console.log(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.51));
console.log(layer.availableDesktopSize(0.49));
```